# Sentence-count function not returning total count

Tags: function, lint

So i've been trying to create a sentence-count function which will cycle through the following 'story':

```
let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';
```

And I realise the problem I'm having but I cannot find a way around this. Basically I want my code to return a the total `sCount` below but seeing as I've returned my `sCount` after my loop, it's only adding and returning the one count as a total:

```
const sentenceTotal = (word) => {
let sCount = 0;
if (word[word.length-1] === "." || word[word.length-1] === "!" || word[word.length-1] === "?") {
  sCount += 1;
};
return sCount;
};
```

```
// console.log(sentenceTotal(story)) returns '1'.
```

I've tried multiple ways around this, such as returning `sentenceTotal(word)` instead of `sCount` but console.log will just log the function name.

I can make it return the correct `sCount` total if I remove the function element of it, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any loop or iterator which would go through `story` to count the number of occurrences of `.`, `?`, or `!`.

Having recently tackled "counting sentences" myself I know it is a non-trivial problem with many edge cases.

For a simple use-case though you can use `split` and a regular expression;

```
story.split(/[?!.]/).length
```

So you could wrap that in your function like so:

```
const sentenceTotal = (word) => {
  return word.split(/[?.!]/).length
};

let story = 'Last weekend, I took literally the most beautiful bike ride of my life. The route is called "The 9W to Nyack" and it actually stretches all the way from Riverside Park in Manhattan to South Nyack, New Jersey. It\'s really an adventure from beginning to end! It is a 48 mile loop and it basically took me an entire day. I stopped at Riverbank State Park to take some extremely artsy photos. It was a short stop, though, because I had a really long way left to go. After a quick photo op at the very popular Little Red Lighthouse, I began my trek across the George Washington Bridge into New Jersey.  The GW is actually very long - 4,760 feet! I was already very tired by the time I got to the other side.  An hour later, I reached Greenbrook Nature Sanctuary, an extremely beautiful park along the coast of the Hudson.  Something that was very surprising to me was that near the end of the route you actually cross back into New York! At this point, you are very close to the end.';

sentenceTotal(story)
=> 13
```

Comment: Thank you! Knew I was missing something. So simple now I look at it xD

Answer (score 0):

There a several strange things about you question so I'll do it in 3 steps :

## First step : The syntax.

What you wrote is the assignement to a *const* of an anonymous variable. So what it does is :

- Create a const name 'sentenceCount'
- To this const, assign the anonymous function (words) => {...}
- Now you have this : `sentenceCount(words){...}`

And that's all. Because what you wrote : `()=>{}` is not the calling of a function, but the declaration of an anonym function, you should read this : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

If you want a global total, you must have a global total variable(not constant) so that the total isn't lost. So :

```js
let sCount = 0; //<-- have sCount as a global variable not a const

function isEndOfSentence(word) {
    if (word[word.length-1] === "." || word[word.length-1] === "!" || word[word.length-1] === "?") {
      sCount += 1;
    };
};
```

If you are forbidden from using a global variable (and it's best to not do so), then you have to register the total as a return of your function and store the total in the calling 'CountWords(sentence)' function.

```
function isEndOfSentence(words) {...}

callingFunction(){

    //decalaration
    let total; 

    //...inside your loop 
    total += isEndOfSentence(currentWord)
}
```

## The algorithm

Can you provide more context as how you use you function ?
If your goal is to count the words until there is a delimiter to mark the end of a sentence, your function will not be of great usage .

As it is written, your function will only ever be able to return 0 or 1. As it does the following :

- The function is called.
- It create a var called sCount and set it to 0
- It increment or not sCount
- It return sCount so 1 or 0

It's basically a 'isEndOfSentence' function that would return a boolean. It's usage should be in an algorithm like :

```js
// var totalSentence = 0
// for each word
//    if(isEndOfSentence(word))
//        totalSentence + totalSentence = 1
// endfor
```

Also this comes back to just counting the punctuation to count the number of sentence.

## The quick and small solution

Also I tried specifically to keep the program in an algorithm explicit form since I guess that's what you're dealing with.

But I feel that you wanted to write something small and with as little characters as possible so for your information, there are faster way of doing this with a tool called regex and the native JS 'split(separator)' function of a string.

A regex is a description of a string that it can match to and when used can return those match. And it can be used in JS to split a string:

```js
story.split(/[?!.]/) //<-- will return an array of the sentences of your story. 
story.split(/[?!.]/).length //<-- will return the number of element of the array of the sentences of your story, so the sentence count
```

That does what you wanted but with one line of code. But If you want to be smart about you problem, remember that I said

> Also this comes back to just counting the punctuation to count the number of sentence.

So we'll just do that right ?

```js
story.match(/(\.\.\.)|[.?!]/g).length
```

Have fun here ;) : https://regexr.com/

I hope that helps you ! Good luck !

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. I am beginner to coding and am in the middle of course starting with JS, so regular expressions are only things I tend to come across in other people's code. Basically what I was doing was a series of tasks for a basic (and I mean basic xD) Mini Linter-esque project and one of the tasks was to get the sentence count. I'll post the remaining tasks in a next comment so you have an idea of it. Much obliged

Comment: 1.In the code editor, there is a string called story. We want to gather some information about the individual words and sentences in the string. Let’s split the string into individual words and save them in a new array called storyWords.


Stuck? Get a hint
2.
Log how many words there are in this story to the console.


Stuck? Get a hint
3.
There is an array of words that are unnecessary. Iterate over your array to filter out these words. Save the remaining words in an array called betterWords. There are several ways that you could achieve this.

Comment: 4.
There is an array of words called overusedWords. These are words overused in this story. You want to let the user of your program know how many times they have used these overused words. There are two ways to achieve this. Try it on your own first. If you need help, consult the hint.


Stuck? Get a hint

Comment: 5.
Now, count how many sentences are in the paragraph.

This may seem tricky, but remember that all of the sentences in this paragraph end with a period (.) or an exclamation mark (!). You could iterate over the array and add 1 to a sentence counter variable for each word that has a period or exclamation mark as its final character.

Comment: 6.
Log these items to the console:

The word count
The sentence count
The number of times each overused word appears
You could choose to simply log them one by one or, for a challenge, create a function that logs all of them with some formatting.

Comment: I see, I understand where you're coming from. 

The idea in those kind of exercise is to be as atomic in your operations as possible, except when specified differently. So apply the return like you did wouldn't have been a good idea either way. 
Try to use more variable to keep track of where you are and respect the naming of your functions. The more you code, the more you'll find a good balance between clarity and efficiency